# Using Newton's Binomial Theorem

Tags: combinatorics

So really, my question has more to do with a very specific step in an example of Newton's Binomial Theorem in my textbook's answer key, and doesn't have much to do with the theorem itself. In any case, The example goes like this:

$$(x^2-x^5)\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} 
\\= (x^2-x^5)\sum_{i=0}^\infty {-3 \choose i}(-x)^i
\\= (x^2-x^5)\sum_{i=0}^\infty {-3 \choose i}(-1)^ix^i
\\= (x^2-x^5)\sum_{i=0}^\infty {3+i-1 \choose i}x^i
$$

So, I'm sure I'm just overlooking something relatively simple, but can anyone explain that last step to me? Specifically, how do we go from having ${-3 \choose i}(-1)^i$ to ${3+i-1\choose i}$?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem and http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Theorem/General_Binomial_Theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'll use $k$ instead of $i$.)

Recall that $\displaystyle \binom{n}k$ means $\dfrac{n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)}{k!}$. So

$$\binom{-3}k = \frac{(-3)(-4)\dots(-3-k+1)}{k!} = \frac{(-1)^k(3+k-1)\dots(4)(3)}{k!} = (-1)^k\binom{3+k-1}{k}$$
and therefore $$(-1)^k\binom{-3}{k} = \binom{3 + k - 1}{k}.$$

In general, by the same reasoning, $$\binom{-n}{k} = (-1)^k \binom{n + k - 1}{k}.$$

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thank you!